# GCC: 'std::is_same_v<int, T>' is not usable in a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

Trying to implement [the following code](https://godbolt.org/z/zPMae4):

```
template <typename R, typename V>
concept SizedRangeOf = 
    std::ranges::sized_range<R> &&
    std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, V>;

template<typename T>
const SizedRangeOf<T> auto getView(std::vector<T>& vec) {
    // helper class
    class vector_view {
        std::vector<T>& vec;
    public:
        vector_view(std::vector<T>& vec): vec(vec) {}
        auto begin() const { return vec.begin(); }
        auto end() const { return vec.end(); }
        std::size_t size() const { return vec.size(); }
    };
    return vector_view { vec };
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 3, 5};
    auto r = getView(v);
    v.push_back(7);
    for(auto val: r) {
        std::cout << val << ' '; // 1 3 5 7
    }
}
```

Compiles and works fine in Clang 11.0 but fails in GCC 10.2 with the following error:

```
the value of 'std::is_same_v<int, T>' is not usable in a constant expression
```

Is it a GCC bug? Or something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97402):

***Bug 97402** - Value of dependent partial-concept-id is not usable in a constant expression.*

<sub>**EDIT 04-Feb-2022:** [Bug is fixed in GCC 11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/4TGG9zhEf)</sub>

---

[Playing with the same code](https://godbolt.org/z/v5aG7o) while trying to make it compile in GCC leads to **`'internal compiler error: Segmentation fault'`**, for a code that compiles fine in Clang.

<sub>**EDIT 04-Feb-2022:** [Also fixed in GCC 11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/hGqTEvrfd)</sub>

---

[Another attempt to play with the code](https://godbolt.org/z/T13KGY) leads to `std::is_same` evaluating to `false` where Clang evaluates it to `true`.

<sub>**EDIT 04-Feb-2022:** [Also fixed in GCC 11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/rGsjjasnT)</sub>

[Implementing our own `is_same`](https://godbolt.org/z/1vdGnh) doesn't help either.

<sub>**EDIT 04-Feb-2022:** [Also fixed in GCC 11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/nr5d3jc5c)</sub>

---

It is to be noted however that using `std::same_as` as part of a concept, ***being used for argument declaration*** [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/KG1xd5).